# how to batch update for db2 database with mybatis

Tags: java, db2, mybatis

as the title, mybatis mapper file,use the **";"** as the delimiter, like this:

```
<foreach colletion="list" item="item" index="index" separator=";">
   update tablename
   set columnname = #{item}
</foreach>
```

but,db2 return the error code: **42601 104**

how to fix it?

Comment: SQLCODE -104 means your actual SQL statement has a syntax error in it.

Comment: Please, show the full mapping (and make sure you copy and paste it as there is no  `colletion` attribute in `foreach` element and the error would be different).